# Accessing URL path in AWS Lambda Authorizer

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, lambda-authorizer

In API Gateway I have a GET endpoint like following (with some request headers too)

```
http://awesomedomain/v1/myspecialkey/find?a=b
```

Is there a way the Lambda (Authorizer) code can read "myspecialkey"?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible, when you are building lambda authorizer you can choose `Lambda Payload Type` to be `Request`.

Assuming that you have named your first lambda parameter `events`, then inside of the lambda, you will have access to your parameter values via

```
event.pathParameters
```

as well as access to your query string via

```
event.queryStringParameters
```

And other request information if needed, such as authorization token which you can extract from `event.headers`.

*the above code uses NodeJs syntax, the same logic holds true for Java but you will need to modify it according to Java syntax*